# How to test an iOS app using the `xcodebuild` command which uses the OpenAPIGenerator Plugin?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, github-actions, openapi-generator

I want to use an GitHub Actions Workflow to run tests for my iOS App. This app uses the OpenAPIGenerator Plugin to automatically have access to the models defined in the backend.

First I build the app and then I run this command to run the tests:

```bash
xcodebuild test -scheme AppName -project AppName.xcodeproj -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=17.0.1,name=iPhone 15 Pro' CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO DEVELOPMENT_TEAM= CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO -skipPackagePluginValidation -sdk iphonesimulator
```

And I get the error:

```
Testing failed:
_OpenAPIGeneratorCore is only to be used by swift-openapi-generator itself-your target should not link this library or the command line tool directly.
Command SwiftCompile failed with a nonzero exit code
Testing cancelled because the build failed.
```

I am expecting that the tests run like beforehand.
I understand the error message but I don't know how to solve it. [This image shows the current build phases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLGP7.png).

I already had a look at [this tutorial](https://swiftpackageindex.com/apple/swift-openapi-generator/0.1.3/tutorials/swift-openapi-generator/clientxcode#Configuring-your-target-to-use-the-Swift-OpenAPI-Generator-plugin) on how to configure the OpenAPIGenerator and at [this thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/732178) in the apple dev forum.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's the same issue as here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/732178?answerId=756684022#756684022

You might be accidentally linking the generator itself, but that's not correct. Only the runtime library and transports should be linked with your app. The generator should be set as a dependency and added as a plugin, but NOT linked to the app.

If you go through this tutorial again, it calls out which checkboxes should be checked and unchecked. https://swiftpackageindex.com/apple/swift-openapi-generator/0.3.3/tutorials/swift-openapi-generator/clientxcode

Comment: Hi czechboy, thank you for your answer. I already had a look at it and it doesn't look like I am doing it wrong. Have you seen the screenshot I linked? This looks correct doesn't it?

Comment: Edit: Also tried to move the generated client to its own specific target. I still get the same error.